# Python package works fine except when downloaded from PyPI (AttributeError)

Tags: python, package, pypi

I am developing a Python package for laser beam analysis. The source code (`setup.py`, `tox.ini`, `travis.tml`) can be found on the [Git repo](https://github.com/wagnojunior/beamprofiler) and the complete documentation can be found on the [ReadTheDocs](https://beamprofiler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) page. The package is uploaded to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/beamprofiler/) and the tests are run with [Travis CI](https://app.travis-ci.com/github/wagnojunior/beamprofiler).

Here is a brief description of the package structure:

```
beamprofiler
|
|---__init__.py
|---beam.py
|
/---utils
|   |
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---data_processing.py
|   |---plot.py
|   |---report.py
|
/---iso
|   |
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---characterizing_parameters.py
|   |---measured_quantities.py
|
/---niso
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---characterizing_parameters.py
```

Currently all tests are **passing** in Travis CI, and I can install and run my package locally with `python setup.py install` without any issues (tests also pass locally).

**Here is the catch:** when I download the package from PyPI I get the following errors:

- `AttributeError: module 'beamprofiler.utils' has no attribute 'plot'`
- `AttributeError: module 'beamprofiler.utils' has no attribute 'report'`

Upon further investigation I found that all other sub-packages and modules are present, even the module `beamprofiler.utils.data_processing`, which is from the same `utils` sub-package. So it seems that this isn't an issue with the sub-package `utils`, but rather with the modules `plot` and `report`.

```
beamprofiler
Out[14]: <module 'beamprofiler' from 'C:\\Users\\wagnojunior.ab\\Anaconda3\\envs\\beam\\lib\\site-packages\\beamprofiler\\__init__.py'>

beamprofiler.beam
Out[15]: <module 'beamprofiler.beam' from 'C:\\Users\\wagnojunior.ab\\Anaconda3\\envs\\beam\\lib\\site-packages\\beamprofiler\\beam.py'>

beamprofiler.iso
Out[16]: <module 'beamprofiler.iso' from 'C:\\Users\\wagnojunior.ab\\Anaconda3\\envs\\beam\\lib\\site-packages\\beamprofiler\\iso\\__init__.py'>

beamprofiler.niso
Out[17]: <module 'beamprofiler.niso' from 'C:\\Users\\wagnojunior.ab\\Anaconda3\\envs\\beam\\lib\\site-packages\\beamprofiler\\niso\\__init__.py'>

beamprofiler.utils
Out[18]: <module 'beamprofiler.utils' from 'C:\\Users\\wagnojunior.ab\\Anaconda3\\envs\\beam\\lib\\site-packages\\beamprofiler\\utils\\__init__.py'>

beamprofiler.utils.data_processing
Out[19]: <module 'beamprofiler.utils.data_processing' from 'C:\\Users\\wagnojunior.ab\\Anaconda3\\envs\\beam\\lib\\site-packages\\beamprofiler\\utils\\data_processing.py'>

beamprofiler.utils.plot
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [20] in <cell line: 1>
    beamprofiler.utils.plot

AttributeError: module 'beamprofiler.utils' has no attribute 'plot'


beamprofiler.utils.report
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [21] in <cell line: 1>
    beamprofiler.utils.report

AttributeError: module 'beamprofiler.utils' has no attribute 'report'
```

I thought it might be a broken wheel file so I rebuilt the project and checked with `twine check dist/*` with no issues:

```
Checking dist\beamprofiler-1.0.0-1-py2.py3-none-any.whl: PASSED
Checking dist\beamprofiler-1.0.0-1.tar.gz: PASSED
```

After that I re-uploaded to PyPI but the problem still persists... I cannot get my head around it, so I appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to PyPI. Actually, I got the same behaviour when installing via `python setup.py install` or `pip install .`

You need to add `from . import data_processing, plot, report` in your `src/beamprofiler/utils/__init__.py` file (I recommand to do it also in your other `__init__` files).

This is the way python works. If these imports are not in your init file, you can only import them with `from beamprofiler.utils import plot`, but you can't directly use `beamprofiler.utils.plot`.

Note that all the other cases you mentionned worked because they where imported in your `src/beamprofiler/beam.py` file (all, except `plot` and `report`). Try to comment out `from beamprofiler.beam import Beam` in your main init file and you will see that it will create the same behaviour with your other modules:

```
>>> import beamprofiler
>>> beamprofiler.utils.data_processing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'beamprofiler.utils' has no attribute 'data_processing'
```